# rails, logger in development mode: console vs logfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

Rails 3.0, to the extent it matters.

So, ordinarily in development mode, logger messages end up written to
both development.log AND console, if you're in an interactive console.

Which is just spiffy, fine.

But something I can't figure out, if I write a logger message during the
boot process (say in config.after_initialize), then this does NOT
happen. The log message is in the log/development.log file, but NOT
written to console. Which is annoying, the reason I'm writing something
out during the boot process (echo'ing certain config) is for the
developer to see it, because it aids in debugging.

Anyone have any idea what's going on here, and if there's anything I can
do about it?

Comment: Are you running tail -f log/development.log within Termainal?

Comment: nope. without doing anything special, normally when you start Rails with "rails server", you see logging output in your console/terminal. Wait, I'm not the only one this happens to, am I?

Comment: Tailing the Development and Test logs are alway a much better idea then using the server request outputs. Give it a go. If you do the following and change the [WHATULOOKFOR] with what you are trying to look for in the log then you know that watching the server output is not the right thing to do when looking for custom logs - 

tail -f -n 500 log/development.log | egrep --color -E '[WHATULOOKFOR]|$'

Comment: Thanks, but still interested in an answer to my actual question, looking at the outputs in console works conveniently in many cases, hasn't been a problem for me in general (when it's there).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is to add a print statement before your logger call, eg:

```
config.after_initialize do
  print Rails.logger.info("Testing")
end
```

The Rails console won't automatically display anything while it's initializing, but it will display anything you pass it with a print statement.  Rails.logger returns the value it writes to the log, so it really is as simple as this.

Comment: thanks a lot! Makes sense now that you say it. Thanks for knowing the answer to my question and answering it instead of telling me I shouldn't want to do what I asked!

I kinda forgot that the 'print' method even existed!